# Setting up router on a college network

Tags: wireless-networking

The scenario is this:

There is a LAN port which is hooked into a computer and then we must log in to a particular site (say *internet.univ.com*) to access internet.

Now I want to add a wireless access point at my end, which is allowed by the way, but it isn't working the way it should be.

What actually happens is that each person has to separately login to *internet.univ.com* to access the internet.

What I want is that logging in once on the router should allow all others connected to the router to access the internet without logging in.

How do I achieve this?

Off-topic question:

Is the way the router is currently behaving similar to a hub or a switch?. My guess is a hub. (I'm actually new to networking, so I don't really know).

Comment: You should take this up with your college's IT department. Chances are they will tell you that you can't do it the way you want, and that each user must authenticate separately.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Well, it so happens that earlier once when I set up the router, it asked for only a single login. Then when I set up another router and tried the same thing, it started asking for multiple logins

Comment: What may have happened in the past is no guarantee that it will continue to work in the future. However, you still need to contact your college's IT department; each network has its own requirements, and SuperUser doesn't know what those requirements are for your (unidentified) college.

Answer (score 0):

If your router is using bridging, then it is acting more like a switch/hub, resulting in the university's network seeing the different MAC-48 addresses.

However, the university's network might be using some more advanced technologies to try to detect who is connecting to it.  Maybe browser cookies are being used?  It's hard to say what's happening without more specific information about the university's setup, because there are so many approaches that might be used (possibly with more or less accuracy as the university guesses when multiple computers are being used).  Other techniques, usable to more or less effect, might involve private SSL certificates, or TCP fingerprinting (maybe also called OS fingerprinting).

Check that you have bridging off (and probably also check to make sure you have NAT on).  That's the easy answer.

Additional specific steps may require specific details (like who manufactured the university's equipment) to realistically/possibly give additional guesses (by people who have knowledge about that specific equipment).